# Listen for GPS Status change

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

I need to listen when the user turns GPS on or off, and act upon that.
I understand this was available using the `GPSStatus` class, however that was deprecated.
How do I do this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LocationListener !!

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                            + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //handlePostion(loc);
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }
```

And below how to use this listener

```
mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, mLocationListener);
```

And in on providerDisabled callback you can know when the GPS is off

Comment: Why do you declare mLocationListener twice on second block?